# dockerfile for creating a custom jenkins image

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, dockerfile, devops

Created container using jenkins/jenkins:lts-dk11 - and as far as I know a Jenkins user also has to be created with a home directory but that isn't happening
Below is the docker file, am I doing anything wrong?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11
WORKDIR /var/jenkins_home
RUN apt-get update
COPY terraform .
COPY sencha .
COPY go .
COPY helm.
RUN chown -R jenkins:jenkins /var/jenkins_home
```

Built with:

```
docker build .
```

The image gets created, container also gets created, I do see Jenkins user with id 1000 but this user has no home dir, and moreover, helm, go, sencha, terraform are also not installed.
I did exec into the container to double-check if terraform is installed or not
#terraform --version, I see command not found
#which terraform also shows no result.
same output for go, sencha and helm

Any suggestions?

Comment: How do we install sencha cmd, sencha cmd requires interactive session when running docker build .

Answer (score 0):

You need install the binaries in the `/usr/local/bin/` path, like this example:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11

WORKDIR /var/jenkins_home

RUN apt-get update

COPY terraform /usr/local/bin/terraform
```

Btw, the docker image `jenkins:lts-jdk11` is based in debian distribution so you can use the apt package manager for install your apps.

Comment: Yes jenkins:lts-jdk11 is based on Debian but how do we install "Sencha", it requires interactive session to license agreement,installation path etc

Comment: New error:
#docker run <img>
Can not write to /var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log. Wrong volume permissions?

Comment: looks like to install sencha you need to get terminal access of the container, make the changes and then commit it for new image. One can not install Sencha through dockerfile since human intervention is required when installing it